# AJAX AutoCompleteextender without webservice

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

As per my knowledge, we can use AJAX AutoCompleteextender via two ways either using 'Webservice' or by defining Service method in 'ASPX or ASCX' file.

I just wanted to know that is there any advantage in using webservice for AutoCompleteextender instead of writing Service method in ASPX or ASCX file?

|Thanks|

Comment: Could someone please answer to my question? I am still waiting for responses.

Comment: Good question. I was wondering the same thing. It looks like the way they are written is very, very similar so I don't really see a point in having 2 different ways of doing the same thing. :/

Answer (score 0):

The webservice advantage is that it centralizes your lookups.  You can have one webservice asmx page with several methods that all your other pages could use if needed.  That would prevent having to have a separate Page Method on each document.  Your lookups would be normalized over your entire site.